# How can I export my learned ClassiferFunction[] and PredictorFunction[]s?

Tags: function-construction, export, machine-learning, neural-networks

Mathematica 10 provides beautiful high-level machine learning functionality. Sadly, the learned functions once created are rather opaque objects. I need to use them in other projects, so here is my question:

**Can I export the neural networks, random forest decision trees, or any other internals of the learned functions for externally use, e.g. can I export a neural net into a standard FANN File format.**

PS. My real hope is to use *Mathematica* **V10** to generate machine-vision convolutional neural networks and then embed them within my clojure, pythons and iOS projects.

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing. Also, I don't believe v10 machine learning supports convolution nets, and exporting image processing related code is not easy.

Comment: This question has been asked last year. Are there any worthy updates?

Comment: Any further development on this? I saw in recent videos that they discussed exporting models.

Comment: Any more updates?

Comment: If OP's interest is for neural networks (convolutional or not) specifically:  You can export trained networks in ONNX format https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/ONNX.html

Comment: I tried to save a trained gradientBoostedTree PredictorFunction as CDF with forms. It is successful, but (with my not so good Form making skills.. ) only can predict 1 value at a time (input was values entered manually..).  I don't know how to 'call' the CDF via command line (that's the original plan then...)

Answer (score 25):

It's on our list of things to do, but there are many other areas we want to cover, such as custom feature functions, customizable feature selection, boosting, NLP, deep learning of neural networks, convolutional nets, GPU acceleration, and so on.

Until then, your only real solution is to deploy your trained classifier as an API function. Some simpler classifiers and predictors can output a pure function that is fairly easy to translate 'by hand':

```
p = Predict[{{1.3, "P"} -> 1, {1.8, "Q"} -> 2.5, {1.9, "Q"} -> 3, {0.2, "P"} -> 1,        
               {-3.2, "P"} -> -4.2, {0.3, "Q"} -> 2}];

PredictorInformation[p, "Function"]
```

> ```
> 0.452129 - 0.530351 Boole[#2 === "P"] + 0.530351 Boole[#2 === "Q"] + 1.12488 #1 &
> ```

Comment: And Bayesian networks with the ability to edit/provide your own nets please! This is a showstopper for me.

Comment: Hi from 2017 ! Any news ?

Comment: @mazieres I encourage you to file this as a suggestion with technical support. I don't work on this feature.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon any update on this?

Comment: Are there any updates this? Is there a way now to export or compile `ClassifierFunction` in general?

Answer (score 7):

TLDR : I had successfully implemented ("exported" + tested + verified) mathematica's GradientBoostedTree PredictorFunction[] model in python.

By "exported", I mean thoroughly matched the each predicted values (mathematica vs python).

Here is the a simplified workflow :

1. On the trained GradientBoostedTree (I name it 'p7mmv')
   PredictorFunction, do `Information[p7mmv,"MethodOption"]`
2. referring to wolfram docs, found that it was an implmentation of https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ .

   a) with exactly the same training & validation set, train the new model.

   b) As for the setting use all info from [1], n apply it here https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html
3. Run the prediction output and compare (all).

Just wish to share on a (small) successful mathematica trained model re-make story.. Any clarifications/comment/improvements is welcomed.