# How can I export neural network code from Mathematica?

Tags: export, neural-networks

I have used `Classify` function to train a series of photos using neural network, and I want to export the code so that I can use it elsewhere without *Mathematica*.

Is there any one who can help me with this? Or how to extract the structure of the neuralnetwork so I can put it into somewhere else?

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56319/how-can-i-export-my-learned-classiferfunction-and-predictorfunctions?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

If you train a network directly with `NetTrain` (say, starting from a pre-trained `NetModel`), you will be able to export the net to MXNet's format starting in Mathematica 11.2, which will be released soon. It is as simple as writing `Export["mynet.json", net, "MXNet"]`. This will also produce a "params" file, and it is then straightforward to load both the JSON and params file from C++ using MXNet (see http://mxnet.io/api/python/symbol.html#mxnet.symbol.load).